# How to force MATLAB to not compute as Inf

Tags: matlab, floating-point

I am trying to work through some code that I wrote and one specific line is giving me problems in MATLAB:

```
Ts = (1+(DatesMod.*Bs)./VolMod).^(VolMod);
```

VolMod is an array with values on the order of 10^8, DatesMod has a range of values between 700,000 and 740,000, and Bs has a range of values between 0 and 100. Note that this function is mathematically similar to doing lim(n->Inf) (1+B*Dates/n)^n. I understand that this primarily has to do with the methods of allocating numbers on the computer. Is there a clever way I can force it to compute the actual value instead of returning Inf for every value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the limit

```
lim(n->Inf) (1+B*Dates/n)^n = exp(B*Dates)
```

and that `exp` will overflow to `Inf` once the argument is greater than `709.9`, so there is no real way to compute `Ts` exactly without arbitrary precision arithmetic.

The best option is probably work in log-precision, e.g. instead of `Ts` you work with `logTs`

```
logTs = VolMod .* log1p((DatesMod.*Bs)./VolMod)
```

You would then need to rewrite any subsequent expressions to use this without explicitly computing `exp(logTs)` (as that will overflow).